# Kafka producer giving TimeoutException

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I have Kafka running in a remote server and I am using spring framework (java) to produce and consume messages. For testing on my local machine, I am just producing 1 event. Here is a simplified code of how I produce messages:

```
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;

...

@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

...

kafkaTemplate.send("sampletopic", "1234").get();

...
```

Here payload is just a user-id string. When I execute the send function, I get the following error:

> kafka.. error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send;
>   nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException:
>   Expiring 1 record(s) for sampletopic-0: 30028 ms has passed since
>   batch creation plus linger time

Here are the relevant logs I get before getting the error:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig - ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    block.on.buffer.full = false
    bootstrap.servers = [41.204.196.251:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    interceptor.classes = null
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    timeout.ms = 30000
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 0.10.2.0
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : 576d93a8ds0cf421
```

Comment: Make sure you're using same ip `41.204.196.251` while producing msg from spring

Comment: DEBUG logging for `apache.kafka` might help; I have seen similar problems when the client/server don't have matching config - e.g. SSL or not SSL.

Comment: were you able to figure out what the problem was?  I am running into similar issue.  I am running kafka on a home server and trying to send/receive messages using spring app on my laptop.
My spring boot app fails to start due to below exception

`org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata`

Comment: I have resolved the problem.  The solution is to change the listeners property from `listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092` to `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`. Using the IP Address of `0.0.0.0` allows Kafka to listen to connections from outside the machine whereas having `localhost` only allows connecting from within the same machine.